# How to redirect Route 53 zone apex to an outside domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a domain that's hosted on AWS Route 53 (example.net) and another one for which there's a completely different registrar (example.com), which is currently linked to a website.
How can I do a permanent redirect for example.net (zone apex, from within Route 53) to example.com?

Answer (score 0):

To do a permanent redirect for example.net (Route 53) to example.com (Third Party Domain Registrar), you must enable forwarding and masking on third party domain registrar. Try  the following steps:

1. Logon to the third party registrar
2. Check if there is an edit option to manage domains and click on that edit option for example.com
3. Edit domain forwarding as http://www.example.com and select 301 Permanent Forwarding
4. Now edit sub domain forwarding as http://example.com and select 301 Permanent Forward with Masking
5. Add a new CNAME Alias with www points to example.net

That's it. Save all of this and select TTL as 1/2 hour and the changes will be reflected in on or before half an hour time.

And now when you enter example.net, you will be forwarded to example.com.