# How to redirect my Amazon Lightsail domain to a facebook page?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

I have a wordpress on Amazon Lightsail on let's say MyWebsite.com, however, while the worldpress is under construction, I want everyone that visits MyWebsite.com to be redirected to my facebook page, let's say facebook.com/MyPage

When the wordpress is complete, I want to be able to reverse this and point it back to wordpress' static-ip.

I've searched for answers on google and stackoverflow and I've found some answers but not to my problem exactly. For example on this thread [How to redirect Route 53 zone apex to an outside domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696769/how-to-redirect-route-53-zone-apex-to-an-outside-domain) they want to change example.com to example.net, but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Creating an "A Record" seems to require an IP for what you redirect to, which I don't have.
Creating a "CNAME record" fails with an error. The error when I do it on Route 53 says that it can't be done on the root, and on lightsail itself it says "Must be a valid domain name".

In the pictures below you will see what I have access to (Lightsail, Route-53, but there is no S3 bucket associated):

[image: Lightsail]

[image: Route-53]

[image: S3-Bucket]

Comment: You cannot redirect a domain to a Facebook page using Route53.

Comment: If I can't redirect to my Facebook page using Route53, is there another way I can do it in Amazon Lightsail? If so, how?

Comment: No, Lightsail does not support redirection to another service either but your WordPress application running in Lightsail can. Redirection is an HTTP application feature. You would need a service running HTTP that can redirect the client. Redirection is not performed at the DNS level. Route 53 can **failover** to another service that is configured via IP or domain name (not domain name + path which would be required for a Facebook page). I would use an S3 static website for a maintenance page while the main site is being developed.

Comment: I think this answers it completely. Thank you very much for the information.